# MySQL Workbench : error "Incorrect string value" when migrating PostgreSQL data into MySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, mysql-workbench, unicode-string

I have an encoding problem while migrating data from a PostgreSQL datatabase to a MySQL database through the MySQL Workbench Migration wizard on Windows.

PostgreSQL is version 12
MySQL is version 8
My Windows is WIndows Seven

My source db is in postgreSQL, in UTF8 encode with 'COLLATION : C" and CHARACTER TYPE : C".
MySQL default options for encoding in Options file are :
character-set server : utf8
collation-server : utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
default_collation_for_utf8mb4 : utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

I have no problem to go through the Migration wizard process (db connections, schema retrieval and re-creation, etc...) 
But as the import is running, I always end up with the same error message as soon as the import cross a VARCHAR data with an "é" (or an "à" or an "è") :

Statement execution failed: Incorrect string value: '\xE9' for column 'xxxx' at row y:

*I HAVE checked the "Driver sends data already encoded as UTF-8" in data transfer setup, nonetheless.*

[image]

*I also tried to indicate "ClientCharset=UTF-8" in the advanced parameters of the source db connection in the wizard => no impact.*

[image]

I do not understand why the `é` character is not read correctly as both sides are supposed to be reading utf-8.

Then, basically, if I go through my source db and make an update to replace all `é` by `e` (and `à` by `a` and so on...), the import succeeds. This is easy as I'm working on a small test DB, but cannot be a long term solution to be used with production database.

Does anyone have a clue?